# Subtracting Two Arrays

Tags: python, arrays

I'm new to python and ran into a problem with my code. I'm trying to subtract two arrays, where one has new values appended to it but can not get it to print the new array with the subtracted values. My attempts to fix it has given me values that are just additive of the for loop. Should I be using lambda to try and subtract these two?

```
from array import *
```

class Temperatures:

```
@staticmethod  
def Model():
    days = array('i',[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30])
    recordedtemp = array('i', [63,62,69,76,70,68,71,71,73,74,75,78,77,77,76,76,77,78,78,82,82,82,81,82,82,76,75,81,85,89])

    print("Temperature:")

    for i in days:
        modelarray = array('i'[0]) * 30


        modeltemp = float(0.5904) * i + float(67.048)
        rounding = int(round(modeltemp, 2))
        modelarray.append(rounding)

        print(modeltemp)

        continue
    print("Error:")
    a = list(map(lambda x,y: x - y, recordedtemp, modelarray))
    print(a)
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about what you want your results to be? You're recreating the `modelarray` value on every pass through the loop, so it will always have exactly 31 values in it (the original 30 zeros, plus the one appended value). Do you instead want to be replacing the zero values with the new ones? Your later `map` call will ignore any appended values, as it stops mapping when the shortest of the iterables it's given runs out. A final question: Have you considered using `numpy` instead of `array`? `numpy` is specifically designed for numeric computations.

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer, please have a look at the extra code I posted here. It looks like you're coming from something like Java or C# where everything has to be a class. Static methods are very rarely used in Python since we have first class functions. Also, if you're doing scientific-type stuff, look at how much easier NumPy makes your life.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in your code is here:

```
days = array('i',[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30])
recordedtemp = array('i', [63,62,69,76,70,68,71,71,73,74,75,78,77,77,76,76,77,78,78,82,82,82,81,82,82,76,75,81,85,89])

print("Temperature:")

for i in days:
    # modelarray = array('i'[0]) * 30  # original line
    modelarray = array('i', [0]) * 30  # new line with extra comma

    modeltemp = float(0.5904) * i + float(67.048)
    rounding = int(round(modeltemp, 2))
    modelarray.append(rounding)

    print(modeltemp)

    continue
print("Error:")
a = list(map(lambda x,y: x - y, recordedtemp, modelarray))
print(a)
```

You said you're new to Python, so let me also point you in the direction of the [NumPy](http://www.numpy.org/) library for problems like this by rewording your problem using numpy arrays, which allow you to avoid looping over the elements like you have done here. This is what your code would look like using NumPy.

```
import numpy
days = numpy.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30])
recordedtemp = numpy.array([63,62,69,76,70,68,71,71,73,74,75,78,77,77,76,76,77,78,78,82,82,82,81,82,82,76,75,81,85,89])

print("Temperature:")
print(recordedtemp)

modelarray = numpy.round(0.5904*days + 67.048)

print('Error:')
print(recordedtemp - modeltemp)
```

It's also highly probable that you don't need to word this as a class with a static method - remember Python has first class functions, so you can just write a function that does this, or as I have done here, just write the code as a straight script.